# Basic addition not working as expected

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm trying to add two numbers together, and it's giving an odd result.

Here's the code,

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module addition_test(
input clk,
output reg [31:0] probe_00, probe_01
);

reg [31:0] a, b;
reg sel;

always @(posedge clk)begin

    case(sel)

        1'b0 : begin

            a <= 15;
            b <= 5;
            sel <= 1'b1;

        end

        1'b1 : begin

            probe_00 <= {a[1:0],a[31:2]}^{a[12:0],a[31:13]}^{a[21:0],a[31:22]};
            probe_01 <= {a[1:0],a[31:2]}^{a[12:0],a[31:13]}^{a[21:0],a[31:22]} + b;

        end

        default : begin

            sel <= 1'b0;

        end

    endcase

end

endmodule
```

`probe_00` evaluates to C0783C03 as expected, but `probe_01` evaluates to C0783C06, which is off by 2. I expect `probe_01` to be C0783C08.

I've tried simulating this with both Vivado and `iverilog`, and tried both blocking and nonblocking assignments, and I still get the same result.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
$display("%b",b);    
probe_00 = a[1:0],a[31:2]}^{a[12:0],a[31:13]}^{a[21:0],a[31:22]};
probe_01 = {a[1:0],a[31:2]}^{a[12:0],a[31:13]}^{a[21:0],a[31:22]} + b;
```

gives: 00000000000000000000000000000101. That is the entirety of my code, except for my testbench, which only inputs the clock and takes the output from `addition_test()`.

Comment: Hope b did not change elsewhere in your code. Can you print the value of b using $display just at the point where the addition is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the add`+` operator has higher precedence than the xor `^` operator. Put parentheses around the expression

```
probe_01 <= ( {a[1:0],a[31:2]} ^ {a[12:0],a[31:13]} ^ {a[21:0],a[31:22]} ) + b;
```

See *Table 11-2—Operator precedence and associativity* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)